# How I could execute an at command with powershell

Tags: powershell, serial-port, at-command

I have an 3G Huawei device which is see as a disconnected network connection when I plug it. Normally, I should have an automatic connection to the 3G mobile network. For fixing this problem, I have found an AT command, and used it with HyperTerminal. Here is the command :

```
AT^NDISDUP=1,1,"web123"
```

When I open hyperterminal on the 3G device port and write this command, I have an automatic connection to my 3G network.

I'm searching how I could execute this command with PowerShell. I've tried this script :

```
$port=new-object system.io.ports.serialport com9,9600,None,8,One
$port.Open()
$port.WriteLine("AT^NDISDUP=1,1,""web123""")
$port.Close()
```

I get no error, but there is no automatic connection as hyperterminal do, and I'm staying in disconnected network connection status.

Comment: I've found the solution, only a syntax problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link helps me to find the solution : [Sample to use AT command in PowerShell](http://www.sharetechnote.com/html/Handbook_LTE_ATCommand_PowerShell.html)

And then :

```
$port=new-object system.io.ports.serialport com1,9600,None,8,One
$port.Open()
$port.WriteLine("AT^NDISDUP=1,1,`r""web123`r""")
$port.Close()
```